Creating AVD from Compiled AOSP
I have compiled AOSP on a linux machine on Azure and I want to run the compiled android on my local machine using the emulator. I have configured AOSP using lunch aosp_x86_64-trunk_staging-eng and it results in a folder out/target/product/generic_x86_64 with lots of files.
How do I run this compiled version of android on my local computer, without copying the entirety of out folder? That is, what is the minimum set of files I need to copy and what are the steps to run it on my Intel Mac?
I saw some resources online which ask you run make emu_imgs_zip, host the resulting zip at a publicly available URL and put it in SDK, but the make command fails on the latest AOSP with an ninja: unknown target 'emu_imgs_zip' error.

Please provide what branch/tag are you trying to build? I recently had an Android 13 build for my own purposes with x86_64 images running fine on a different x86_64 machine, hence same shall apply but I would recommend you using a release tag / branch.

I am using the current master branch (Vanilla Ice Cream). I just started playing with AOSP so I can change the branch to a tag that you might be able to help with. Can you send the instructions for Android 13?
